# Reactions and free actions (Summoner and Eidolon)

Tags: pathfinder-2e, summoner, eidolon, free-action

I have a Summoner with a Dragon Eidolon, and I'm not understanding some things about the class.

In the following topic: "Your eidolon is no mere minion. It doesn't have the minion or summoned trait, and the two of you work together and coordinate your actions. You and your eidolon share your actions and multiple attack penalty. Each round, you can use any of your actions (including reactions and free actions) for yourself or your eidolon."

Summoner and Eidolon only have 1 reaction and 1 free action shared between the two or do they each have their respective reaction and free action?

I would like that both at the beginning of the combat could use Battle Cry, is it possible? If not, is it a waste to both have battle cry?

That is all. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

## You get one Reaction

As a Summoner/Eidolon pair, you get one Reaction (at the start of your shared turn) that can be used by either creature. See the sections I've bolded for clarity:

> You and your eidolon **share your actions** and multiple attack penalty. Each round, you can use any of your actions (**including** reactions and free actions) for yourself or your eidolon.

If it's the use of "reactions" in plural that has you confused, it's worth noting that there are various ways to get multiple reactions per round. The first ones that come to mind are Feats around level 10 for other classes, such as Fighter and Champion, that you might take with their Multiclass Archetype. It is also necessary as a simple way to keep the text future-proof as more options become available.

Free Actions are not limited per round, but you *are* still limited to one  Action (inlcuding "free" ones) per trigger. Either creature can be the source of your Free Action, but they probably* could not both react to the same trigger because your Actions are **shared**. This is outlined in [Limitation on Triggers](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=390).

> You can use only one action in response to a given trigger. For example, if you had a reaction and a free action that both had a trigger of “your turn begins,” you could use either of them at the start of your turn—but not both.

*This point is a little more shaky than the others, it might be worth asking your GM if they agree with this intent since the Eidolon is shown to have other characteristics that allow it to act independently.

Comment: Eidolon can obtain Skill Feats through the Summoner talent SKILLED PARTNER, so it is possible for him to have access to Battle Cry.

In Limitation on Triggers quotes:
"This limitation of one action per trigger is per creature; more than one creature can use a reaction or free action in response to a given trigger."

The Eidolon is a creature of its own, having its own exploration actions and performing skill checks independently. Even having shared Actions, the same creature is not reacting to the same trigger because they are two different creatures having the same trigger.

Comment: Dang it, I couldn't find the feat when I went through haha. I'll reconsider

Comment: I'm going to stick with my current interpretation (including the P.S. pointing out the fact that it's unclear) based on "can use any of your actions (including reactions and free actions) for yourself **or** your eidolon." I'm not sure if that's the *intent* of that text, but it seems odd to include free actions at all if it wasn't.